# DetailView Django dont work error page not found

Tags: django

When I click on the article I get 
How can I fix it?
 I tried url, path and other but I have this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ee1s.png)
      urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('index', include('mainpage.urls')),
    path('blog', include('news.urls')),
    path('games', include('games.urls')),
    path('fortnite', include('fortnite.urls')),
    path('contacts', include('contact.urls')),
    path('admin', admin.site.urls),
]
news/urls.py
from django.urls import path,include,re_path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from news.models import Articles 
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ListView.as_view(queryset=Articles.objects.all().order_by('-date')[:20],template_name='news.html')),
    path('<int:pk>/', DetailView.as_view(model=Articles, template_name='news/post.html'))       
                ]
```

Comment: Your urls.py, paths are not even having slashes

Comment: Where must I put slashes&

Comment: @misha to the end of url

Comment: from django.urls import path,include,re_path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from news.models import Articles 
urlpatterns = [
 path('/', ListView.as_view(queryset=Articles.objects.all().order_by('-date')[:20],template_name='news.html')),
 path('<int:pk>/', DetailView.as_view(model=Articles, template_name='news/post.html'))

Comment: but i have the same error

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62089508/edit) your post, don't try to expand on it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please add '/' at end of all your path strings , change it like this

```
    path('index/', include('mainpage.urls')),
    path('blog/', include('news.urls')),
    path('games/', include('games.urls')),
    path('fortnite/', include('fortnite.urls')),
    path('contacts/', include('contact.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

check if it works or not